# Why is the ship called the Shenzhou?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

This question is a fairly straightforward one. In the series *Star Trek: Discovery*, Michael Burnham serves as the first officer on the Federation starship U.S.S. *Shenzhou*. I just want to know where the ship received its name. Is it named after a person, city, or something else entirely?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhou_program

Comment: I'm not sure why people are assuming that "Shenzhou" in the fictional Star-Trek universe is the same as the "real" Shenzhou meaning.

Comment: @HamSandwich: There seems to be a certain theme of ships on ST:D possibly being named after real-world space programs or ships. Indeed, any one of them could be named after something else, but seeing that theme repeated across several craft makes it more likely that the authors are following a common theme there - and in this particular case, there is little reason why the naming rationale should be different in-universe than out-of-universe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a Chinese manned space program that began in 1992, putting a Chinese astronaut in space in October 2003. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhou_(spacecraft))

Comment: Shenzhou is also a name for China itself. It means "Divine Land" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_China#Shenzhou